# Angular - Get an array of observables from a observable of observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have to recursivly list all generated `observable` in one array to execute all of this later.

For more context, the object `currentLesson` have a list of activities. But an `activity` can be another `lesson` with another activities as children. I have to (deeply) load all activities before use it. That's why I'm trying to use a recursive function.

This is my code, but at the end of the build there is an error. I understand the error but I don't know why `data` is an `Observable<Observable<DataEntity>>` and not an `Observable<DataEntity>[]` and I don't know how to do it.

## Code :

```js
        const recursivelyGetActivityObservales = (currentLesson: DataEntity): Observable<DataEntity>[] => {
            const obsList: Observable<DataEntity>[] = [];

            const activities: any[] = currentLesson.get('reference');
            for (const activity of activities) {
                if (activity['type'] === 'lesson') {
                    const data = this.getLessonById(activity.id).flatMap(subLesson =>  recursivelyGetActivityObservales(subLesson));
                    obsList.push(...data);
                } else {
                    const loadedActivity = this.activitiesService.getActivityEntity(+activity.id);

                    if (loadedActivity) {
                        obsList.push(from([loadedActivity]));
                    } else {
                        obsList.push(this.activitiesService.loadActivitiesFromId(activity.id));
                    }
                }
            }

            return obsList;
        }
```

## Error :

```
ERROR in src/app/@modules/activities/core/lessons/lessons.service.ts(321,37): error TS2461: Type 'Observable<Observable<DataEntity>>' is not an array type.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
const data = this.getLessonById(activity.id)
                 .flatMap(subLesson => recursivelyGetActivityObservales(subLesson));
```

the function `recursivelyGetActivityObservales(subLesson)` is returning an **array**, not an Observable. FlatMap/mergeMap operators need to **return an observable** in order to work properly.

I don't know what you will do with your final array of observables, but if you are gone a merge it anyway, a quick solution is use the `merge()` operator. Example:

```js
const lessons = (activity) => [
    rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
]

const activity = rxjs.of('activity1');

const toSub = activity.pipe(rxjs.operators.mergeMap((activity) => rxjs.merge(...lessons(activity))))

toSub.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

In your code:

```
const data: Observable<DataEntity> = this.getLessonById(activity.id)
             .flatMap(subLesson =>  merge(...recursivelyGetActivityObservales(subLesson)));
obsList.push(data);
```

**Preferred Solution:**

Said that, IMO the correct **solution** would be just returning the type `Observable<DataEntity>`, since it also represents multiple DataEntity objects. There is no reason to have an array of observables in this use case.

For that, I would just return the merged list. 
Example:

```
const recursivelyGetActivityObservales = (currentLesson: DataEntity): Observable<DataEntity> => {
    const obsList: Observable<DataEntity>[] = [];

    const activities: any[] = currentLesson.get('reference');
    for (const activity of activities) {
        if (activity['type'] === 'lesson') {
            const data = this.getLessonById(activity.id).flatMap(subLesson =>  recursivelyGetActivityObservales(subLesson));
            obsList.push(data);
        } else {
            const loadedActivity = this.activitiesService.getActivityEntity(+activity.id);

            if (loadedActivity) {
                obsList.push(from([loadedActivity]));
            } else {
                obsList.push(this.activitiesService.loadActivitiesFromId(activity.id));
            }
        }
    }

    return merge(...obsList);
}
```

**Explantaion:**

An `Observable<DataEntity>` is a data structure that emits DataEntities (0, 1 or **many**) over and scheduler. So is actually a container (like an array) of DataEntities.
Take this example, where both data structure equals the same output result:

```js
const lessonObsArray =  [ // Observable<DataEntity>[]
    rxjs.of(1),
    rxjs.of(2),
    rxjs.of(3),
    rxjs.of(4),
]

const lessonObs = rxjs.merge( // Observable<DataEntity>
    rxjs.of(1),
    rxjs.of(2),
    rxjs.of(3),
    rxjs.of(4)
);

lessonObsArray.forEach(obs => obs.subscribe(console.log))
console.log('--------')
lessonObs.subscribe(console.log)
// They emit the same!!! (a collection of numbers in this case)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not what I want, I think I have to be more precise. In your `Preferred Solution` the return of the subcription is only one result.
In the sample juste above, the `activities` of the first lesson are correctly load, but only one result are return by the recursive. So finaly I've got only two results.
But I need, in final, that the result of the subscription to be an array of all my activities (deeply and not).

Comment: I have added and 'Explanation' section. Observable<DataEntity> can be a group of multiple DataEntities like and array. There is no reason IMO and AFAIK to have an array of observables in this use case. If you have only 2 results, maybe another thing is wrong on the solution.... we could check it.